# two column fixed-fluid-fixed css layout

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to create a layout where there is a fixed width and **fixed position** sidebar on the left.

The problem is setting the width of the main content area - it stretches off the screen to the right. Here's what I've got:

```
<body>
    <div class="left-sidebar">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        main
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.left-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 220px;
}

.main-content {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 220px;
background: #f0f0f0;
width: 100%;
}
```

How can I have the main content div start at 220px from the left, but only fill the window width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the main content to appear fully left but give it a margin-left to make room for the sidebar.

```
.main-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit:**
I've had a bit of time now to try out the code. I suggested margin-left instead of padding-left because it fits better with what you want to do. Using margin gives you the option of putting a border around your content. Also, if you actually do want padding in the content you can set it as normal. if you used a padding to indent for the sidebar you'd have to add the 220px to whatever actual padding you wanted.

This is what I came up with to get it working with margins instead of padding.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.left-sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.main-content 
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I also agree with the anser referencing dynamic drive. One of the best ways to learn CSS initially is to have a go with a working stylesheet and customise it for your needs. The big advantage is it will already be cross browser compatible. Just use Google to find a bit of inspiration.

Comment: If this fails, try `padding:220px` instead.

Comment: Thanks, padding-left: 220px worked. I just had to adjust the z-index too so that the left-sidebar was on top.